# Is it possible to get backup of Acumatica portal?

Tags: acumatica

Inside of Acumatica I can get data of current company via the following way:  System -> Management -> Manage Companies -> Export Snapshot. Does Acumatica portal has this option also?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the portal has snapshot pages by default however, seeing how the portal shares the ERP database, taking a snapshot from the ERP instance will also get the portal information.

If you really need to do it from the portal itself, seeing how the snapshot functionality is part of the framework, if the pages don't exist you should be able to add them from the production ERP and a customization project then add them to the admin sitemap in the portal.

Comment: I've added those pages to portal, but it didn't imported data